# Rails nested form for has_many :through with an additional field on the join model using Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, has-many-through

I'm trying to do a nested form for a `has_many :through` association using [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), and I can't figure out how to get around this error: `ArgumentError in Variants#edit -- Association cannot be used in forms not associated with an object`.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a "Product Variant" model (called `Variant`). Each variant can have many parts (`Part` model) through a "Parts List Item" (`PartsListItem`) join model. Each variant should be able to have parts assigned to it in different quantities.

For instance, a guitar strap might have a part called "Backing Fabric" that has a quantity of 1. Meaning that the Guitar Strap variant needs 1 of the "Backing Fabric" part to be assembled. But the same variant might also have another part such as "Rivet" that has a quantity of 4. (As in 4 rivets are required to make this product variant.) After using the `Variant` form to add all the parts in various quantities to the variant, I'd like to show all of the parts with quantities on the `variants#show` page.

Here is the relevant code from my models:

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts_list_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :parts, through: :parts_list_items, dependent: :nullify

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
end

class PartsListItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :variant
  belongs_to :part
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts_list_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :variants, through: :parts_list_items, dependent: :nullify
end
```

And my VariantsController:

```
class VariantsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
       if @variant.update(variant_params)
         format.html { redirect_to @variant, notice: 'Variant was successfully updated.' }
       else
         format.html { render :edit }
       end
    end
  end

  private
  def variant_params
    params.require(:variant).permit(:account_id, :product_id, :sku,
                                    :choice_ids => [], :part_ids => [])
  end
end
```

And my form (views/variants/_edit_form.html.erb):

```
<%= simple_form_for @variant do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :parts_list_items do |item| %>
    <%= item.input_field :quantity %>
    <%= item.association :parts %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this works just fine:

```
<%= simple_form_for @variant do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :parts, as: :check_boxes %>
<% end %>
```

So, it works to associate parts directly to the variant through the `PartsListItem` join model. The trouble begins when I start trying to add the quantity for each associated part.

What am I doing wrong with this nested form? Is there a problem with my controllers or associations?

Do I need to create an additional model called `PartsList` that `has_many :parts_list_items` with additional associations? That seems like an extra step and that there should be a way to put the `:quantity` on the `PartsListItem` model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change `parts` to `part`

```
<%= simple_form_for @variant do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :parts_list_items do |item| %>
    <%= item.input_field :quantity %>
    <%= item.association :parts %> <!-- HERE -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned in my question that I tried that. `part` gives me the same error: `Association cannot be used in forms not associated with an object`. It's as if I need to create the association between the part and the variant first and then I can add a `parts_list_item` with a quantity to the variant, but this would preferably be done in a nested form. Seems like I'm struggling with something straightforward.